# How to print a document that exhausts printer memory?

Tags: memory, printer

I'm trying to print the [Pokemon TCG Rulebook](https://assets.pokemon.com//assets/cms2/pdf/trading-card-game/rulebook/sm7_rulebook_en.pdf) for reference, but I can't get a single page out of the printer. It seems the document is just too image-heavy and exhausts the available printer memory. And it's not a wimpy home printer either - it's a big laserjet at my workplace (Kyocera Ecosys M2040dn to be exact).

I tried printing in various ways (double-sided, single sided) and even printing to an XPS document first - but no avail. Are there any tricks that I can use to get the document printed?

Comment: "and exhausts the available printer memory" How do you know this.

Comment: @Moab - The printer prints a single page with an error message that says it ran out of memory.

Comment: Start by screenshotting a page and printing that. If that fixes it, then you could use various tools to export each page as a PNG or similar, and printing it page by page.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is that the pdf exhaust the printer memory, the solution is export the pdf to a lighter version. Alternatively, split the pdf in smaller parts. This software https://en.pdf24.org/ does the job under windows.

PDF24 comes with a "compression" feature. Reducing dpi for images make decreasing the size of the file. This make the whole pdf file "lighter".

Comment: Hmm... I didn't try printing one page at a time. Perhaps that would do the trick. But what do you mean with "lighter version"?

Comment: @Vilx- edited the answer